# Как сделать выборку в JPA

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jpa

Нужна выборка для вывода JSON. 
У меня в объекте около 30 полей. Из них мне нужно вывести 5. К примеру только имя, фамилию и адрес юзера.

Я хочу получить [{"name":"Vasya","surname":"Pupkin","address":"Main str 9"}]

Делаю такую выборку:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT user.name, user.surname, user.address FROM User user")
List<Task> findAll();
```

Мне выводит:[["Vasya","Pupkin","Main str 9"]] т.е без названий полей.

Распарсить это, без названий полей, ясное дело не возможно. Как быть? 
@JsonIgnore не вариант.

Comment: Кто и куда выводит? `[{"Vasya","Pupkin","Main str 9"}]` - это вообще не валидный JSON.

Comment: @enzo Извиняюсь, подправил. Не точно переписал. Но суть вопроса это не меняет.

Comment: Перенесем ждет л б пищи.) Ш

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Извлекайте поля по номеру. Вы же знаете в каком порядке они идут, раз сами его задаёте (своим запросом естественно):

```
List<Object[]> users = em.createQuery(...).getResultList();
for (Object[] u : users) {
    System.out.println(u[0]); // name
    ...
}
```

Другой вариант - использовать операцию `NEW` и конструктор.
Определяете для своей проекции (выборку части полей часто называют проекцией) класс с конструктором, у которого параметры соответствуют полям выборки:

```
package a.b.c;

public class UserPr {
    private String name; // поля
    ...

    public UserPr(String name, String surname, ...) // конструктор с полями как в запросе        

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }    
    ...     
}
```

(Не обязательно делать приватные поля и геттеры к ним. Можно обойтись просто публичными полями)

А теперь операция `NEW`
Запрос JPQL будет выглядеть так:

```
String query = "SELECT NEW a.b.c.UserPr(user.name, user.surname, user.address) FROM User user"
```

Требуется указать полное имя класса `a.b.c.UserPr`

В результате выполнения такого запроса получим `List<UserPr>`:

```
List<UserPr> users = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
for (UserPr u : users) {
    System.out.println(u.getName());
    ...
}
```

Таким нехитрым образом можно сливать результаты запроса во все классы с подходящим конструктором.
Можете даже использовать тот же `User`, если сделаете для него нужный конструктор! Только полученные в результате объекты не будут считаться Entity, со всеми вытекающими.

Не буду расписывать подробно, ограничусь только упоминанием.
Применительно к нативными запросами точно. Насчёт JPQL не помню.
Иногда для таких классов приходится немного подкрутить mapping.
Аннотация `@SqlResultSetMapping` позволяет задать как каждое поле из выборки будет транслироваться в поле класса (точнее параметр конструктора).

Как вместо println получить свой JSON надеюсь сами сообразите.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Как раз вчера нашел в документации. Для тех, кто работает со spring framework: @Query(value = "SELECT new NameSurnameAndAdress (user.name, user.surname, user.address) FROM User user")
List<User> someMethod(); И учтитет, что по крайней мере spring, без гетеров и сетеров мне выдавал ошибку серриализации.